# Panel/DataList - Send the Record ID When Checkbox is checked

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a panel contains DataList, which lists the companies with checkboxes. What I would like to do is when user clicks a checkbox for a specific company, it will send the CompanyID, so I can do some update on the database.  I am not sure how to store the value in the checkbox and send it when user clicks.

Here is the DataList

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlChildView" runat="server" style="padding-left:200px;">
<asp:DataList ID="childList" runat="server" Width="100%">
   <ItemTemplate>
       <div  class="div_hover">
        <table class="table1" width="80%">
       <tr>
          <td style="width: 60%; border-right:0px solid black; border-spacing:0;">&#8226; <%#Eval("CompanyName")%></td>
           <td style="width: 20%;text-align:right; "><a href="/Apps/ERP/Other/CompanyInfo.asp?CompanyID=<%#Eval("CompanyID")%>" ><%#Eval("CompanyID")%></a></td> 
           <td style="width: 20%;text-align:right;"><asp:CheckBox id="chkChildCompany" runat="server"  
                AutoPostBack="true"
               OnCheckedChanged="chkChildCompany_CheckedChanged"  /></td>                     
       </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
</asp:Panel>
```

Below is the event:

```
protected void chkChildCompany_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("Child Checkbox is checked, CompanyID: " + CompanyID (sending from the checkbox event);
}
```

Any idea how to store the CompanyID hidden and capture it when the checkbox click event?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code for aspx file

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Temp._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="compID" Text="" Style="display: none;" />
    <!-- HIDDEN Field for saving data in case posting form -->
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlChildView" runat="server" Style="padding-left: 200px;">
        <asp:DataList ID="childList" runat="server" Width="100%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="div_hover">
                    <table class="table1" width="80%">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 60%; border-right: 0px solid black; border-spacing: 0;">
                                &#8226;<%#Eval("CompanyName")%>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 20%; text-align: right;">
                                <a href="/Apps/ERP/Other/CompanyInfo.asp?CompanyID=<%#Eval("CompanyID")%>">
                                    <%#Eval("CompanyID")%></a>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 20%; text-align: right;">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="chkChildCompany" value="<%#Eval("CompanyID")%>" />
                                <!-- Binding Company id to value -->
                                <%--<asp:CheckBox ID="chkChildCompany" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkChildCompany_CheckedChanged" />--%>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
    </asp:Panel>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.chkChildCompany').click(function () {
                var idarray = new Array();
                 //idarray used to store all checked id
                $("input[class='chkChildCompany']:checked").each(function () {
                  //This is a kind of for loop iterating to all check box 
                  //which have class name chkChildCompany
                  //and also check box is checked
                    idarray.push($(this).val());
                  //Each particular value that bind via DataGrid
                  //is add to id array
                });
                var listofid= idarray;
               //here id array is set to a new field to use as a string
                $('input#compID').val(listofid);
                console.log('listofid:- ' + listofid+ ' input#compID:- ' + $('input#compID').val());
                $.ajax({
                    url: "Default.aspx/saveComanyId", type: "POST", cache: "false",
                    dataType: "json", contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    data: "{'idList':'" + airlinepref + "'}",
                   //here data must contains the var(idList) name defined in WebMethod
                   //saveComanyId(string idList)
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data.d);
                    }, error: function () {
                    }
                });

            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this one for code behind i.e. aspx.cs file

```
namespace Temp
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Company> companyList = new List<Company>{
                new Company{CompanyID=1,CompanyName="AAAA"},
                new Company{CompanyID=2,CompanyName="BBBB"},
                new Company{CompanyID=3,CompanyName="CCCC"},
                new Company{CompanyID=4,CompanyName="DDDD"},
            };
            childList.DataSource = companyList;
            childList.DataBind();
        }
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string saveComanyId(string idList)
        {
            string response = "false";
            try
            {
                var ids = idList.Split(',');
                foreach (var id in ids)
                {
                    //Code for saving id in DATABASE
                }
                response ="true";
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                response="false";
            }
            return response;
            //returing response true for success and false for failure
        }
        /*protected void chkChildCompany_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("Child Checkbox is checked, CompanyID: ");

        }*/
    }
    public class Company
    {
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, it looks so complicated, but I am going to work on it as you suggested. Thank you

Comment: @milacay It is cominationtion of jQuery and c#.If you were using checkbox change event it will postBack the page which is not good for a web page so prefer jquery for that if you want to use in checkbox change event I'll provide that one also

Comment: Thanks alot of taking time to help. If you don't mind, please provide me the checkbox change event method also.  I am new and trying to learn asp.net.

Comment: what is the "airlinepref" I ran error on that on? please advise.